# File scanning problem?

Tags: errors, compiling

OK, I found the wrong part, maybe someone can help me in correcting:

```
$\alpha - \beta x \begin{cases} >0, & \text{0<x<\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\\ =0 & \text{x=0 \lor x=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\\ <0,x> \frac{\alpha}{\beta}}$`

enter code here\documentclass[10pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Vorlesung Gewöhnliche Differentialgleichungen WS 16/17}

\paragraph{§1 Problemstellung und Grundbegriffe}


\paragraph{1.1 Einige klassische Beispiele}


\paragraph{Beispiel 1.1 (Radioaktiver Zerfall)}

Betrachte eine radioaktive Substanz. 
Sei $x(t)$ die zur Zeit $t$ vorhandene Masse. 
Dann ist $x'(t)=\dot x(t)=lim_{\Delta t \to 0} (\frac{\Delta(t+\Delta t)-x(t)}{\Delta t})$ 
ist die Zerfallsrate (Veränderung) zur Zeit $t$. 
Die zeitliche Entwicklung wird beschrieben durch $x'(t)=-\alpha x(t)$ für ein geeignetes $\alpha>0$. 
Alle Lösungen haben die Gestalt $x(t)=c \cdot e^{-\alpha \cdot t}$ mit einer Konstanten $c>0$.
$\newline$
Zum Beispiel: 
$x'(t)=-\alpha \cdot c \cdot e^{-\alpha t} $
$<=> -\alpha \cdot x(t) = -\alpha \cdot c \cdot e^{-\alpha t}$

$\newline$
Sei $\tau$ ein fester Zeitpunkt und $\xi$ gegeben. Oft sucht man Lösungen der DGL, welche zusätzlich $x(t)=\xi$ erfüllen.
Dies führt auf $x(t)=\xi \cdot e^{-\alpha (t-\tau)}$,also $c=\xi \cdot e^{\alpha \tau}$.
$\newline$


Beispiel 1.2 (erzwungene Schwingungen)
Sei $x=x(t)$ die Abweichung der Höhe des Gewichts mit der Masse $m$ von der Ruhelage. Die erste Ableitung $x'(t)$ ist die Geschwindigkeit zur Zeit $t$, die zweite Ableitung $x''(t)$ ist die Beschleunigung. Newtonsches Kraftgesetz:
"Kraft = Masse $\cdot$ Beschleunigung"
$m \cdot x''(t)=-Dx(t)+A \cdot sin(\omega \cdot t), D>0$ Federkonstante, $A>0$ Amplitude, $\omega>0$ Frequenz der äußeren Anregung , $\omega_0=\sqrt{(\frac{D}{m})},a=\frac{A}{m} \Rightarrow x''=-\omega_0^2\cdot x+ \cdot sin(\omega t)$
1.Fall:
$\omega_0 \neq \omega:$
Jede Lösung hat die Form $x(t)=\frac{a \cdot sin(\omega t)}{\omega_0^2 - \omega^2}+b \cdot sin(\omega_0 t -\varphi)$ mit $b,\varphi \in \Bbb R$.
Insbesondere gilt: $sup_{t\in \Bbb R}|x(t)|< \infty$,d.h die Lösung ist beschränkt.

2.Fall:$\omega_0 = \omega:$ "Resonanzkatastrophe":
Die Lösung ist komplizierter und für $t \to \frac{+}{-} \infty$ unbeschränkt.

Beispiel 1.3:(Populationswachstum):
Es sei $x=x(t)$ die Größe einer Population zur Zeit $t$ und $x'(t)$ deren Änderungsrate.
Die sogenannte logistische Gleichung ist $x'(t)=\alpha x(t)-\beta x(t)^2, \alpha,\beta>0$, wobei $\alpha$ die Vermehrungsrate und $\beta x(t)^2$ "soziale Reibung"
$x'=(\alpha-\beta x)x ,x>0$
%$\alpha - \beta x \begin{cases} >0, & \text{0<x<\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\\ =0 & \text{x=0 \lor x=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\\ <0,x> \frac{\alpha}{\beta}}$
man zeigt : $x(0)>0 \Rightarrow lim_{t \to \infty}x(t)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$
$\newline$
Beispiel 1.4:(Planetenbewegungen)
Betrachtet werden zwei Himmelskörper mit den Massen $m>0$ und $M>0$, wobei $M>>m$,z.B. ein Planet und eine Sonne, welche wir ins Zentrum $0 \in \Bbb R^3 \setminus\{0\}$ die Position des Planeten relativ zur Sonne. 
Dann sind $\dot x(t)\in \Bbb R^3$ die Geschwindigkeit, sowie $\ddot{x(t)}\in \Bbb R^3$ die Beschleunigung.
Das Newton'sche Gravitationsgesetz sagt:
$m\ddot{x(t)}=-\gamma Mm\frac{x(t)}{||x(t)||^3}$
$\newline$
\paragraph{1.2 Allgemeines} 
Man beschäftigt sich mit Gleichungen der Form $F(t,x,x',x'',....,x^{(n)})=0 (*)$ mit $n\in \Bbb N$ ("Ordnung") und einer Funktion $F:\Omega \to \Bbb R^m$ auf einem gewissen Defintionsbereich $\Omega \subset \Bbb R x \Bbb R^{N(n+1)}$ mit $t\in \Bbb R, x\in \Bbb R^N$
Für $M=1$ heißt $(*)$ eine implizite DGL n-ter Ordnung,für $M\ge 2$ spricht man von einem System
$$\begin{cases}
F_1(t,x,x',x'',......,x^{(n)})=0 \\ \vdots \\F_m(t,x,x',x'',......,x^{(n)})=0
\end{cases}$$
$\newline$
Beispiel 1.5:
$M=3,N=4,n=4
e^{x_1''+cos(x_2)}=\frac{x_2''''}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2}, x_1'''=12(x_2'')^2
sin(x_1+x_2+x_1'+x_2''+x_3+x_4')=0$
$\newline$
Bemerkung 1.6:
Die Klasse der impliziten Differentialgleichungen ist sehr groß, i.A. werden diese eine Lösung haben, wie in Beispiel $sin(x(t)+x'(t))=2$.
Wir beschäftigen uns deswegen mit expliziten Differentialgleichungen der Form $x^{(n)}=f(t,x,x',x'',...,x^{(n-1)})(**)$
$\newline$
Satz 1.7:
Jedes explizite DGL-System n-ter Ordnung ist äquivalent zu einem expliziten DGL-System erster Ordnung.
Genauer:
(a)Ist $x:I \to \Bbb R^N$ eine Lösung von $(**)$, so ist die Funktion $z:I \to \Bbb R^{Nn},z(t)=(x(t),x'(t),....,x^{(n-1)(t)})$ ist die Lösung von $z'=g(t,z) (***)$ mit $g:G \to \Bbb R^{Nn}$
definiert durch $g(t,z)=(z_2,....,z_n,f(t,z))$ für ein geeignetes $G \subset \Bbb R x \Bbb R^{Nn}$ und $z=(z_1,...,z_n)\in \Bbb R^{Nn}$
(b) Ist umgekehrt $z:I \to \Bbb R^{Nn}$ eine Lösung von $z'=g(t,z), so ist x:I \to \Bbb R^N, x(t)=z_1(t)$ Lösung von (**).
$\newline$
Beweis:
(a)$z'(t)=(x'(t),x''(t),.....,x^{(n)(t)}) =(z_2(t),....,f(t,z(t)))=g(t,z(t))$ für $t\in I$
$\newline$
(b) $z$ ist Lösung 
$\Rightarrow (z_1'(t),z_2'(t),....,z_n'(t))=z'(t)=g(t,z(t))=(z_2(t),z_3(t),...,f(t,z(t))$
$$\begin{cases}
z_1'(t)=z_2(t) \\z_2'(t)=z_3(t) \\ \vdots \\z_n(t)=?
\end{cases}$$
$x(t)=z_1(t) \Rightarrow x^{(n)}(t)=z_1^{(n)(t)=z_2^{(n-1)}(t)=z_3^{(n-2)}(t)=....=z_n'(t)=f(t,z(t))=f(t,x(t),x'(t),.....,x^{(n-1)}(t))}$ qed
$\newline$  
Beispiel 1.8:
$x''=-\omega^2x-6x'+x^3+sin(t)
f(t,x,x')=-\omega^2x-6x'+x^3+sin(t)$
$\newline$
Setze $v=x', z=(x,x')=(x,v)$
Es ergibt sich: $z'=g(t,z)=g(t,x,v)=(v,f(t,x,v))$
$\newline$
$v=x'
v'=x''=-\omega^2x-6x'+x^3+sin(t)$
$\newline$
$\binom{x}{v}'=\binom{v}{-\omega^2x-6x'+x^3+sin(t)}=g(t,\binom{x}{v})$
$\newline$
Bemerkung 1.9:
Folgende Verallgemeinerungen sind wichtig:
(a)man könnte $z\in\Bbb C$ oder $t\in \{a+ib: a\in\Bbb R, \-epsilon < b < \epsilon\}$ betrachten und kommt zu analytischen Differentialgleichungen.
(b)partielle DGLen: $t\leftarrow$ eine Variable bei gewöhnliche DGLen, partielle DGLen sind Beziehungen zwischen den Ableitungen einer Funktion mehrerer Veränderlicher:
$(i)\Delta u(x)=0$ für $u=u(x_1,....,x_n),\Delta u(x)=\sum_{j=1}^n \frac{(\partial^2u)}{\partial x_j^2}(x)$(Laplace-Operator)
$(ii)u_{zz}(t,x)-\partial u(t,x)=0$ für $u=u(t,x_1,....,x_n)\in \Bbb R$
$u_{zz}=\frac{(\partial^2u)}{\partial t^2}$ Wellen-Gleichung
$(iii)u_{zz}+/- \partial(t,x)=0$ Schrödinger-Gleichung
$\newline$
Definition 1.10:
Sei $x'=f(t,x)$ ein DGL-System erster Ordnung mit einer Funktion $f:G \to \Bbb R^N$ und seien $(\tau,\xi)\in G$. Unter einer Lösung eines Anfangswertproblems (AWP) versteht man eine Funktion $x:I \to \Bbb R^N$ mit den folgenden Eigenschaften:
(a)$I \subset \Bbb R$ ist ein (nicht-einpunktiges)Intervall $\tau \in I$
(b)$x:I \to \Bbb R$ ist differenzierbar mit $(t,x(t))\in G \forall t\in I$ sowie $x'(t)=f(t,x(t)) \forall t \in I$
(c)$x(t)=\xi$
Ist $\sim x:\sim I \to \Bbb R^N$ eine weitere Lösung mit $I \subset \sim I$ und $\sim x|_I=x$, so heißt $\sim x$ eine Fortsetzung von x.
Besitzt x keine echte Fortsetzung, so heißt x nicht fortsetzbar oder maximal, und I heißt dann maximales Existenzintervall für das AWP.
$\newline$
Beispiel 1.11:
$x'=-x^2, x(t)=\xi$; hier ist $N=1, f(t,x)=-x^2, G=\Bbb R^2$
$1.Fall: \xi=0 \leftarrow x:(\tau-\frac{1}{\xi},\infty) \to \Bbb R,x(t)=(t-\tau+\frac{1}{\xi})^{-1}$ ist Lösung des AWPs:$x(\tau)=\xi, x'(t)=-()^2=-x^2(t)$
Diese Lösung ist nicht fortsetzbar, also maximal.
$2.Fall: \xi=0 \leftarrow x(t)=0 \forall t\in \Bbb R$ ist die maximale Lösung.
$3.Fall: \xi<0  \leftarrow x:(-\infty,\tau+\frac{1}{|\xi|})\to \Bbb R, x(t)=(t-\tau-\frac{1}{|\xi|})$ ist die nicht-fortsetzbare, also maximale Lösung.
$\newline$
\paragraph{§1.3 Geomtreische Veranschaulichung von DGLen}
$\newline$
Betrachte die skalare DGL $x'=f(t,x)$, also $N=1$ und $G \subset \Bbb R x \Bbb R$ im Punkt $(t,x)$zeichnen wir eine kurze Strecke mit Steigung $f(t,x)$.
Dann heißt $(t,x,f(t,x))$ ein Linienelement im Punkt $(t,x)$.
Die Gesamtheit dieser Linearelemente heißt Richtungsfeld. Die Lösung der DGL ist dann eine Funktion, der Graph der Richtungsfeld folgt,d.h. die Linearelemente sind Tangenten des Graphen.
$\newline$
ZEICHNUNG
$\newline$
Hilfe beim Zeichnen von Richtungsfeldern bilden die sogenannte Isolation,d.h. die Linien gleicher Stteigung $\{(t,x)\in G:f(t,x)=c, fest\}$
$\newline$
Beispiel:
$x'=tx$, also $N=1;G=\Bbb R^2,f(t,x)=tx, 
c=0. t=0 $oder $x=0$,d.h. die Achsen
$c\neq 0:$ Hyperbeln
$\newline$
Defition 1.14:
Sei $U \subset \Bbb R^N$ und $f:U \to \Bbb R^N$ eine Funktion.
Dann heißt $x'=f(x)$ eine autonome DGL, (d.h. $G=\Bbb R x U$)
Die Funktion $f$ heißt dann ein Vektorfeld.
$\newline$
Beispiel 1.15:
(a)
(b)
(c)
$\newline$$
$\paragraph{§2 Spezielle Lösungsmethoden}
$\newline$
2.1 Die lineare DGL x'+x g(t) = h(t)
$\newline$
Sei $I \subset \Bbb R$ ein Intervall und seien $g,l:I \to \Bbb R$ stetig.
Der Name "Linear" erklärt sich wie folgt:
Seien $x,y$ Lösungen, $\lambda \in \Bbb R ,n=0 \leftarrow x+ \lambda y$ ist Lösung, wegen 
$(x+\lambda y)'+g(t)(x+\lambda y)=x'+x g(t)+\lambda (y'+g(t)y)=0+0=0$
Als Kontrast: $x'+g(t)x^2=0$ ist nicht-linear.
$\newline$
$I$ Der Spezialfall $x'=h(t)$
Satz 2.1:
Sei $h:I \to \Bbb R$ stetig, $\tau \in I$. Die DGL $x'=h(t)$ hat die allgemeine Lösung $x(t)=\int_\tau^t h(s) ds + c, t\in I, c\in \Bbb R$.
D.h. alle diese Funktionen sind Lösungen und es gibt keine weiteren Lösungen.
Für $\xi \in \Bbb R$ hat das AWP mit $x(\tau)=\xi$ die eindeutige Lösung $x(t)=\int_\tau^t h(s) ds + \xi$.
$\newline$
Beweis:
Hauptsatz der Differential- und Integralrechnung qed
$\newline$
Beispiel:
$x'=t^2, x(0)=4 \leftarrow x(t)=\frac{t^3}{3}+4$
$\newline$
$II$ Die homogene lineare DGL $x'+g(t)x=0$
Sei $g:I \to \Bbb R$ stetig und $x:J \to \Bbb R$ eine Lösung mit $J \subset I$
1.Fall: $x(t)>0 \forall t\in J:$
Dann gilt: $\frac{x'(t)}{x(t)}=-g(t)$
$\leftarrow ln(x(t))'=-g(t) \forall t\in J$
Sei $G$ eine beliebige Stammfunktion von $g$ 
$\leftarrow ln(x(t))=-G(t)+c_* $ mit einer beliebigen Konstanten $c_* \in \Bbb R$
$\leftarrow x(t)=e^{-G(t)}e^{c_*}$
$\leftarrow x(t)= c e^{-G(t)} \forall t \in J$ mit $c>0$
$\newline$
2.Fall: $x(t)<0 \forall t\in J:$
Dann ist $-x$ Lösung von $x'+xg(t)=0$ und $-x(t)>0 \forall t\in J$
$\leftarrow x(t)=c e^{-G(t)} \forall t \in J $ mit $c<0$
$\newline$
3.Fall: $\exists s \in J : x(s)=0.$
Dann gilt aber $x(t)=0 \forall t \in J$
(andernfalls gäbe es ein Intervall $[a,b]\subset J$,s.d. $x>0$ auf $[a,b]$ gilt, sowie $x(a)=0$ oder $x(b)=0$.
$O.E. x>0 in [a,b]$
3.1Fall:
$\leftarrow x(t)=ce^{-G(t)} \forall t \in (a,b), x stetig$
$\leftarrow x(t)=ce^{-G(t)} \forall t\in [a,b] und x(a)=0 oder x(b)=0)$
$\newline$
\end{document}
```

Comment: We need to get a better MWE to answer. Your mistake is rather somewhere else than in this preamble. Check if you didn't delete \end{document} or forget to close any other environment.

Comment: You should better look directly in the log-file to check the exact wording of the error message. Editors quite often don't show the correct line and text and so can be quite misleading.

Comment: @sztruks: Shall I upload a bigger screenshot ?

Comment: @pinkpanther5: Your tex-file is simple text which you can copy and paste. There is no reason to hide it in a screenshoot and so make it more difficult for us to test it.

Comment: When you have so many {} and $$, the good way to check is to comment some lines with %, trying to find out which pieces of your doc LaTeX is able to compile. I am not a scientist, so I cannot help you that much digging in your file.

Comment: @sztruks: It works now !! Thank you so much for the idea with commenting !! :D

Comment: You're welcome. Please add an answer to your question, so that people won't spend some time on something already solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @gernot told me in another question: we do have to obey the aesthetics also.  Therefore I place an answer instead of just an comment.

You are using an article.  The highest sectioning command is the `\section`command, whereas the lowest is the ˚\subparagraph`.  You are starting your document with`\paragraph`.  You are inserting the sections numbers yourself, e. g.

```
\begin{document}
\paragraph{Vorlesung Gewöhnliche Differentialgleichungen WS 16/17}

\paragraph{§1 Problemstellung und Grundbegriffe}


\paragraph{1.1 Einige klassische Beispiele}


\paragraph{Beispiel 1.1 (Radioaktiver Zerfall)}
```

(Taken from your document!)

As you can see: you are using the paragraph as a title, as a section and as an extra example section.  I'd say: you are misusing this command.  (Sorry, don't want to offend you, please take it as advice and not insult!)

The fact, that you are not seeing section numbers, when using `\parapgraph` is simple to explain.  Human minds tend to forget faster, the longer the words or numbers are.  Therefore, the sections numbers will only be shown down to a defined level.  In an article class that should be `\subsubsection`.  (The same applies to the Table of Contents.)  You can easily change that behaviour in LaTeX.

Please us a correct usage of sectioning commands in your document, making it also logical correct.

Next, you usually have to use `\S` to get the §-sign.

EDIT: This is a shortened MWE, how you should write your document.

From what I saw, let me make the following points: If you really need to give a lecture this winter term, you should better use existing scripts instead of inventing the wheel anew.  A good lecture handout needs a looooot of time.  Dont underestimate that!  This point can not be stressed to much!  Especially if you don't have a) the time and b) the knowledge of basic LaTeX (as is obvious to me) as your writing tool.  You should stick to OpenOffice-Writer or similar word processors, you are familiar with.  You will get more pleasant results in shorter time, as you don't have to learn a complete new tool.  (I don't want to say, LaTeX is a wrong choice.  It isn't at all.  But if you are short a time, it will be a very difficult task, to manage the tool and to have enough resources at hand, to do a good writing!)

To me, it seems, as if you where using LaTeX the first time and tried to use it in a similar way, someone unexperienced user would use OOo-Writer and Co.  (E. g. the way you are introducing equation numbers and the way, you refer to those numbers, among many other things.)

If you have time, to learn LaTeX, writing a lecture handout, will a good lesson learned.  But be prepared to invest a lot of time, to learn your new tool and do yourself the favor, to ask some experienced users about typography and such related topics.  Ask frequently, to avoid learning the wrong habits!

One source could of course be TeX.SE.  There is a lot to learn here.

As a general matter of fact: Have yourself an outline or sketch of your document at hand, before your actually begin writing.  You can easily transfer a handwritten outlined sketch into your (most empty) LaTeX file by typing down the contents just in form of `\section`, `\subsection`, `\subsubsection`-commands and so on.  Have a `\tableofcontents`-entry after `\begin{document}` and `\maketitle`.  Thus you can run latex (twice will suffice) and get an outline printed in the table of contents.

When writing, pick yourself the next topic and concentrate on that.  Put the meat on the empty bone skeleton.  Write short sentences.  Write clear sentences.  After having completed one thought, type the ENTER-key twice, to produce one single blank line in your input file (which is your LaTeX file).

Don't worry about the formatted output a lot.  As long, as your LaTeX-file compiles and the structure is correct, leave any questions as "how to change the width of the margins?", "how to change to Times New Roman?") aside.  Concentrate on content and logic than on layout.

Make a lot of usage of comments, to note, what you did and why you did it.  If there is still text, graphics, etc. missing, make yourself a note like "`%%TODO`" in your LaTeX file, to remind yourself about it.  (It wont appear in your output file!)

Try to work out the logical sense, of what you are describing.  Try to object that logic also in your document.  Being clear and sharp will endorse your document structure a lot.  Think: here begins a unnumbered list, ... here it ends.  Say (better type:) `\begin{itemize} ... \end{itemize}`.

Get yourself a good LaTeX intro in printed form. The "LaTeX-Kurzanleitung" is a good starting point.

Get yourself acquainted with LaTeX by independently learning each lesson, before incorporating it in your great document.

Here are my corrections to your document.  I hope you don't mind.

```
%% Maybe you really need an report or book instead of an article?!
%% Nevertheless, I argue, to use KOMA-Script classes, which are
%% scrartcl or scrreprt or scrbook.  To save paper, use option
%% "twoside" in any case.  There is no excuse, to stay with "oneside"
%% any more.
\documentclass[10pt,,twoside,a4paper]{scrartcl} % better adapted to german needs
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[main=german,english]{babel} % german hyphenations, quotes, ...
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}

%% A new definiton, to get some Lemma and such:
\newtheorem{satz}{Satz}
\newtheorem{beweis}{Beweis}[section] 


%% Definition of the pagestyle.  Headings will draw a title on the top
%% of the page.
\pagestyle{headings}


%% Definition for the title(page).
\title{Vorlesung Gewöhnliche Differentialgleichungen WS 16/17}
\author{Pink Panther}
\date{{Im Dezember 2016}}


%% End of preamble.  Now the document beginns.
\begin{document}

%% Make a title(page).  On report and book classes, a complete
%% titlepage is issued.  Article classes do only a "titleblock".
\maketitle

%% Also: do include a Table of Contents
\tableofcontents


%% First section.
\section{Problemstellung  und  Grundbegriffe}
\label{sec:problemstellung}
%% always set a \label after sectioning commands.  Set it directly
%% afterwards, don't set any!! other command, don't loose any time.
%% The content within the brace must be unambigous!  It should be
%% easy to memorize, in order to be easily retrieved when you want to
%% use it in a referencing command, i. e. \ref{sec:problemstellung} or
%% \pageref{sec:problemstellung}.


\subsection{Einige klassische Beispiele}
\label{sec:beispiele}

\subsubsection{Beispiel Radioaktiver Zerfall}
\label{sec:radioakt-zerfall}


Betrachte eine radioaktive Substanz.  Sei $x(t)$ die zur Zeit $t$
vorhandene Masse.
%% X' should be written as $x^{\prime}$ 
%% Some better german text, to introduce the $\dot{x}$:
Die erste Ableitung nach der Zeit der Funktion $x(t)$, also
$x^{\prime}(t)$ wird in der Technik auf häufig als $\dot{x}(t)$
geschrieben.  Demzufolge wird die zweite Ableitung nach der Zeit mit
einem doppelten Punkt über der Variable geschrieben: $\ddot{x}(t)$
%% The following equation should not be presented in text as "inline"
%% equation, but instead be displayed as a paragraph of its own.  In
%% that case, you call it a displayed formulae.  Correctly you should
%% use another environment.  The \displaymath-environment or
%% equation-environment are both able to display one single line of
%% code her.  There must not be white lines in the environment!  The
%% equation environment will also print a equation number.  The
%% equation number can be referenced, as you can reference a section.
%% In this case, you should have a environment, that is capable of
%% more than one line, as you intend to rearrange your equation
%% contents.  You could use the eqnarray-environment.  In the
%% eqnarray, you place the relation sign (most of the times the "=")
%% between an ampersand as this: "& = &".  New lines will be
%% introduced by a double backslash
Dann ist die Zerfallsrate (Veränderung) zur Zeit $t$:
\begin{eqnarray}
  x^{\prime}(t) & = & \nonumber \\
  \dot{x}(t) & = & lim_{\Delta t \to 0} \left (\frac{\Delta(t+\Delta t)
                   -x(t)}{\Delta t} \right)
  \label{eq:1}
\end{eqnarray}
%% Why the () around the fraction?  If needed, use \left and \right to
%% give them the appropriate height

%% You introduced $\dot{x}$, than you should use it!
Die zeitliche Entwicklung wird beschrieben durch
$x^{\prime}(t) = -\alpha x(t)$ für ein geeignetes $\alpha > 0$.  Alle
Lösungen haben die Gestalt $x(t)=c \cdot e^{-\alpha \cdot t}$ mit
einer Konstanten $c>0$. 

%% \newline is a text command.  You should not use it in math mode as below.
% $\newline$ 
%% It would be better, to insert a blank line in your LaTeX-file.
%% That will produce a new paragraph in the output.  (Normally the new
%% paragraph is in output indented, but not separated by a empty
%% line.  You can also change that.)
Zum Beispiel:
%% Again: use the correct environment.  
%% Iinstead of <=> use \Leftrightarrow
%% Use \quad or \qquad to separate the arrow and the formulae
%% Leave those \cdot away.
\begin{eqnarray}
  \dot{x}(t) & = & -\alpha c e^{-\alpha t} \\
  \Leftrightarrow\quad -\alpha x(t) & = & -\alpha c e^{-\alpha t}
\label{eq:2}
\end{eqnarray}

Sei $\tau$ ein fester Zeitpunkt und $\xi$ gegeben. Oft sucht man
Lösungen der DGL, welche zusätzlich $x(t)=\xi$ erfüllen.  Dies führt
auf $x(t)=\xi e^{-\alpha (t-\tau)}$, also
$c=\xi e^{\alpha \tau}$.


\subsubsection{Erzwungene Schwingungen}
\label{sec:erzwungene-schwingungen}


Sei $x=x(t)$ die Abweichung der Höhe des Gewichts mit der Masse $m$
von der Ruhelage. Die erste Ableitung $\dot{x}(t)$ ist die Geschwindigkeit
zur Zeit $t$, die zweite Ableitung $\ddot{x}(t)$ ist die
Beschleunigung. Es gilt dabei das Newtonsches Kraftgesetz, nachdem
eine Kraft das Produkt aus der Masse eines Körpers und seiner
Beschleunigung sind.
%% German quotes are eithter (shortform when using german style)
%% "`Anführungszeichen"'.  The correct form would be
%% \glqq{}Anführungszeichen\grqq{}. 
%% USe complete sentences.
% "Kraft = Masse $\cdot$ Beschleunigung"
$m \ddot{x}(t)=-Dx(t) + A \sin(\omega t)$ mit $D>0$, Federkonstante,
$A>0$ Amplitude, $\omega>0$ Frequenz der äußeren Anregung.

\begin{eqnarray}
  \omega_0 & = & \sqrt{\frac{D}{m}} \\
  a & = &\frac{A}{m} \\
  \Rightarrow \quad \ddot{x} & = & -\omega_0^2 x \sin(\omega t)
\label{eq:3}
\end{eqnarray}

%% Here you could use a numbered list, which is automatically numbered
%% by LaTeX.
Es gibt folgende Lösungen
\begin{enumerate}
\item $\omega_0 \neq \omega:$ Jede Lösung hat die Form
$x(t)=\frac{a \sin(\omega t)}{\omega_0^2 - \omega^2}+b \sin(\omega_0 t -\varphi)$,
mit $b,\varphi \in \Bbb{R}$.  Insbesondere gilt:
$sup_{t\in \Bbb{R}}|x(t)| < \infty$, d.\,h.\ die Lösung ist
beschränkt.
\item $\omega_0 = \omega$: hierbei handelt es sich um eine sog.\
  "`Resonanzkatastrophe"'.  Die Lösung ist komplizierter und für
  $t \to \pm \infty$ unbeschränkt.
%% use \pm  to present the plus/minus sign.  \mp is the minus/plus sign.
\end{enumerate}


\subsubsection{Populationswachstum}
\label{sec:populationswachstum}


Es sei $x=x(t)$ die Größe einer Population zur Zeit $t$ und
$\dot{x}(t)$ deren Änderungsrate.  Die sogenannte logistische
Gleichung ist $\dot{x}(t)=\alpha x(t)-\beta x(t)^2$, mit  $\alpha,\beta>0$,
wobei $\alpha$ die Vermehrungsrate und $\beta x(t)^2$ "`soziale
Reibung"' sind.

\begin{equation}
  \dot{x}  =  (\alpha-\beta x)x, \quad x>0
\end{equation}
% \begin{equation}
%   \alpha - \beta x \begin{cases} >0, & \text{0<x<\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\\
%       =0 & \text{x=0 \lor x=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}\\ <0,x>
%         \frac{\alpha}{\beta}}
%     \end{cases}
% \end{equation}
Man zeigt:
$x(0)>0 \Rightarrow lim_{t \to
  \infty}x(t)=\frac{\alpha}{\beta}$

\subsubsection{Planetenbewegungen}
\label{sec:planetenbewegungen}

Werden zwei Himmelskörper mit den Massen $m>0$ und $M>0$, wobei
$M>>m$, z.\,B.\ ein Planet und eine Sonne, welche wir ins Zentrum
$0 \in \Bbb{R}^3 \setminus\{0\}$ die Position des Planeten relativ zur
Sonne.  Dann sind $\dot x(t)\in \Bbb{R}^3$ die Geschwindigkeit, sowie
$\ddot{x}(t)\in \Bbb{R}^3$ die Beschleunigung.  Das Newton'sche
Gravitationsgesetz sagt:
$m \ddot{x}(t)=-\gamma Mm\frac{x(t)}{||x(t)||^3}$

\subsection{Allgemeines}
\label{sec:allgemeines}


Man beschäftigt sich mit Gleichungen der Form
$F(t,x,\dot{x},\ddot{x},\dots,x^{(n)})=0 (*)$ mit $n\in \Bbb{N}$
("`Ordnung"') und einer Funktion $F:\Omega \to \Bbb{R}^m$ auf einem
gewissen Defintionsbereich
$\Omega \subset \Bbb{R} \times \Bbb {R}^{N(n+1)}$ mit
$t\in \Bbb{R}, x\in \Bbb{R}^N$ Für $M=1$ heißt $(*)$ eine implizite DGL
$n$-ter Ordnung,für $M\ge 2$ spricht man von einem System

%% I am no mathematician, but I am sure, this usage is not the
%% intended usage.  Use \dots to create three (not more!) dots.
\begin{equation}
\begin{cases}
  F_1(t,x,\dot{x},\ddot{x},\dots,x^{(n)})=0 \\ \vdots \\F_m(t,x,\dot{x},\ddot{x},\dots,x^{(n)})=0
\end{cases}
\label{eq:6}
\end{equation}

\subsection{Beispiel 1.5}
\label{sec:beispiel-1.5}


$M=3,N=4,n=4
e^{x_1\prime\prime+cos(x_2)}=\frac{x_2^{\prime\prime\prime\prime}}{1+x_1^2+x_2^2}, x_1^{\prime \prime \prime}=12(x_2^{\prime \prime })^2
sin(x_1+x_2+x_1^\prime+x_2^{\prime\prime}+x_3+x_4^{\prime})=0$


\subsection{Bemerkungen}
\label{sec:bemerkungen}


Die Klasse der impliziten Differentialgleichungen ist sehr groß,
i.\,A.\ werden diese eine Lösung haben, wie in Beispiel
$sin(x(t)+\dot{x}(t))=2$.  Wir beschäftigen uns deswegen mit
expliziten Differentialgleichungen der Form
\begin{equation}
  x^{(n)}=f(t,x,\dot{x},\ddot{x},...,x^{(n-1)}) \label{eq:expl-dgl}
\end{equation}

%% Use the theorem definition from the preamble.
%% use \ref{eq:expl-dgl} to get the correct equation number.  Use "~"
%% to prevent line wrap.
\begin{satz}
  Jedes explizite DGL-System n-ter Ordnung ist äquivalent zu einem
  expliziten DGL-System erster Ordnung.

  Genauer: 
  \begin{enumerate}
  \item Ist $x:I \to \Bbb R^N$ eine Lösung von
    Gleichung~(\ref{eq:expl-dgl}), so ist die Funktion
    $z:I \to \Bbb R^{Nn},z(t)=(x(t),\dot{x}(t),....,x^{(n-1)(t)})$ ist
    die Lösung von $z'=g(t,z) (***)$ mit $g:G \to \Bbb R^{Nn}$
    definiert durch $g(t,z)=(z_2,....,z_n,f(t,z))$ für ein geeignetes
    $G \subset \Bbb R x \Bbb R^{Nn}$ und
    $z=(z_1,...,z_n)\in \Bbb R^{Nn}$
  \item Ist umgekehrt $z:I \to \Bbb R^{Nn}$ eine Lösung von
    $z'=g(t,z), so ist x:I \to \Bbb R^N, x(t)=z_1(t)$ Lösung von (**).
  \end{enumerate}
\end{satz}

\begin{beweis}
  \begin{eqnarray}
    z^{\prime}(t) & = & \dot{x}(t)\\
    \ddot{x}(t),\dots^{(n)(t)} & = & z_2(t), \dots ,f(t,z(t)) \nonumber\\
                   & = & g(t,z(t))
  \label{eq:4}
  \end{eqnarray}
  für $t \in I$ 

  $z$ ist Lösung \dots 

  Setze $v=\dot{x}, z=(x,\dot{x})=(x,v)$
  Es ergibt sich:
  \begin{eqnarray}
     z^{\prime} & = & g(t,z) \\
                & = & g(t,x,v)\\
                & = & (v,f(t,x,v))
    \label{eq:5}
  \end{eqnarray}
  \end{beweis}
\end{document}
```